# "Application Actions" in Ember 2.1

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-2

I'm trying to create a modal for my users to signin, so I have this link:

```
<li><a {{action "signin"}}>Sign In</a></li>
```

in a `{{planhw-navbar}}` component.

```
{{planhw-navbar signin=(action "showModal" name="signin-modal")}}
```

But when I open my browser, I get the error:

> An action named 'showModal' was not found in (generated application controller)

I've tried putting an action in a controller, a route, and a component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    showModal: function(name) {
      this.render(name, {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'modal'
      });
    }, //...
  }
})
```

My component, `{{signin-modal}}`, works correctly.

My entire `application.hbs`:

```
{{planhw-navbar signin=(action "showModal" name="signin-modal")}}
{{outlet}}
{{outlet 'modal'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an action called showModal in your application.js controller.